# Merge observables but return both

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'd like to merge two observables with the second one requiring the result of the first.

Simple enough:

```
const booking$ = this.service.getBooking$(bookingId);

const result$ = booking$.pipe(mergeMap(booking => this.service.getMoreData$(booking.someField))
```

However the return type of result$ is only the result of the "getMoreData$".

How do I return both booking$ and getMoreData$? Is there a specific operator?

Comment: Just `pipe` the inner observable, then `map` it through `(moreData) => ({ moreData, booking })`. That way the subscribers get an object containing the booking and the additional data.

Comment: Absolute legend! Can't say that was too intuitive! Thank you very much.